# Need SumIf based in two Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I Need Help I need a SUMIF, when name and date are match.

```
Date   Jun Jun Mar Jun
Name1  10  11  14  12
Name2  2   34  4   7
```

Need Result

```
Date  Jun  Mar
Name1  33   14
Name2  43   4
```

Comment: The answers below are good but I'd recommend restructuring your data if it's feasible. It would be easier to work with just three columns: Name, Month, Value. Not only could you use just `SUMIFS` for this problem, many other things would become easier, too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is laid out like with "Date" in `A1` and "7" in `E3`, you can do:

`=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$3=$A8,IF($B$1:$E$1=B$7,$B$2:$E$3)))`

Be sure to enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bruce Wayne's solution is a good one.  There is a simpler (but slightly less flexible approach) available also:
`=SUMIF($B$1:$E$1,"="&B$7,$B2:$E2)`

`$B$1:$E$1` is the range the condition is being tested against. The row and columns are both anchored, because I am always testing against the same array of month names.

`"="&B$7` is the condition.  Here the row is anchored, because I will always be looking at the month names in row 7, but the column is not, because I want to drag this across my table and have it apply to whichever column header it is under.

`$B2:$E2` Is the range that will be summed by `sumif`  Now the column is anchored, but the row is not, because I want to drag down, and have it apply to the Name# in columnA.

This approach requires a little more care with your $ signs - to make sure that the proper Name# is being referred to, etc.  It also requires that your names are in the same order in the summary table as they are in the starting table.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Ah, nice thinking with not anchoring the rows.